# Split string using a newline delimiter with Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I need to delimit the string which has new line in it. How would I achieve it? Please refer below code.

Input:

```
data = """a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
j,k,l"""
```

Output desired:

```
['a,b,c', 'd,e,f', 'g,h,i', 'j,k,l']
```

I have tried the below approaches:

```
1. output = data.split('\n')
2. output = data.split('/n')
3. output = data.rstrip().split('\n')
```

Comment: What is the output of `repr(data)`?

Answer (score 291, accepted):

[`str.splitlines`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) method should give you exactly that.

```
>>> data = """a,b,c
... d,e,f
... g,h,i
... j,k,l"""
>>> data.splitlines()
['a,b,c', 'd,e,f', 'g,h,i', 'j,k,l']
```

Comment: One convenient part about `str.splitlines` is that it will remove the final `\n` if its present. I.e, `'foo\nbar\n'.split() == ['foo', 'bar', '']` while `str.splitlines('foo\nbar\n') == ['foo', 'bar']`

Answer (score 16):

If you want to split **only by newlines**, you can use [str.splitlines()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_splitlines.htm):

*Example:*

```py
>>> data = """a,b,c
... d,e,f
... g,h,i
... j,k,l"""
>>> data
'a,b,c\nd,e,f\ng,h,i\nj,k,l'
>>> data.splitlines()
['a,b,c', 'd,e,f', 'g,h,i', 'j,k,l']
```

With [str.split()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) your case also works:

```py
>>> data = """a,b,c
... d,e,f
... g,h,i
... j,k,l"""
>>> data
'a,b,c\nd,e,f\ng,h,i\nj,k,l'
>>> data.split()
['a,b,c', 'd,e,f', 'g,h,i', 'j,k,l']
```

However if you have spaces (or tabs) it will fail:

```py
>>> data = """
... a, eqw, qwe
... v, ewr, err
... """
>>> data
'\na, eqw, qwe\nv, ewr, err\n'
>>> data.split()
['a,', 'eqw,', 'qwe', 'v,', 'ewr,', 'err']
```

Comment: seems strange that you don't have to pass the character to split by like `data.split('\n')`?

Answer (score 15):

```
data = """a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
j,k,l"""

print(data.split())       # ['a,b,c', 'd,e,f', 'g,h,i', 'j,k,l']
```

`str.split`, by default, splits by all the whitespace characters. If the actual string has any other whitespace characters, you might want to use

```
print(data.split("\n"))   # ['a,b,c', 'd,e,f', 'g,h,i', 'j,k,l']
```

Or as [@Ashwini Chaudhary suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042948/split-string-with-newline-using-python/22042968#comment33419729_22042968), you can use

```
print(data.splitlines())
```

Comment: Just to be on the safer side use `.splitlines`, what if the strings have spaces, etc.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yup, that is why I suggested `split("\n")`. Is `splitlines` better than `.split("\n")`?

Comment: It will work for `\r\n` and other type of line boundaries as well.

Comment: If your string ends in a `\n`, `splitlines()` will ignore it while `split("\n")` will have an additional empty string `""` at the end of the result.

Answer (score 7):

There is a method specifically for this purpose:

```
data.splitlines()
['a,b,c', 'd,e,f', 'g,h,i', 'j,k,l']
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
>>> data = """a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
j,k,l"""
>>> data.split()  # split automatically splits through \n and space
['a,b,c', 'd,e,f', 'g,h,i', 'j,k,l']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the split gets a string as separator you should have additional back slash
output = data.split('\n')

Answer (score 0):

We can also use regex's split method too.

```
import re

data = """a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
j,k,l"""

output = re.split("\n", data)

print(output) #['a,b,c', 'd,e,f', 'g,h,i', 'j,k,l']
```

Hope this will help somebody.