# Add a new line after a given character in a python string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a single, very long string that s output from a python function and need to split it onto multiple lines each time a \n is found.

I know I can use regex, but I'm not entirely sure how.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string using a newline delimeter with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042948/split-string-using-a-newline-delimeter-with-python)

Comment: This question does not solve my issue. I have a single string I need to split by the characters mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you don't have to use regex to solve your this task because it may work too slow for big strings. I would use `io.StringIO` (or `StringIO.StringIO` if you're using Python 2.7) to process your string:

```
from io import StringIO

s = "qwe\nrty\nuio"

s_stream = StringIO(s)
for line in s_stream:
    print(line) # it prints data line by line
s_stream.close()
```