# how to make a list that contains elements as each line of the input in python

Tags: python, list

```
s = "how many gallons
     of rain did you drink
                                cuckoo"
```

above 3 lines are input ,
I want to create a list=`["how many gallons", "of rain did you drink", "cuckoo"]`

Comment: I thought about it while solving a problem, is it simple to do or code for it is complicated ,if latter is the case then I will think to solve the problem with some other approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string using a newline delimiter with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042948/split-string-using-a-newline-delimiter-with-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `splitlines`:

```
print([i.strip() for i in s.splitlines()])
```

Output:

```
['how many gallons', 'of rain did you drink', 'cuckoo']
```