# Python extend list

Tags: python, list, extend

I'm running into a bit of difficulty trying to extend a list.

The problem section of code is:

```py
l = []

tickers = soup.find_all('td', {'aria-label': 'Symbol'})[1:].text

l.extend(tickers)
```

When I print tickers it comes out as expected with one ticker per line. However, when I try to add them to a list, it shows as one letter per line. Even when I save it to csv it's one letter per line.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: To add a single element to a list, use `.append()` rather than `.extend()`.

Comment: There is an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042948/split-string-using-a-newline-delimiter-with-python) which suggests `splitlines()`

Comment: `tickers` is a string. When you use a string as a sequence, it's a sequence of characters, not lines.

Comment: "When I print tickers it comes out as expected with one ticker per line." Yes, because it has newline characters in it - but it is still **one string**. "However, when I try to add them to a list, it shows as one letter per line." Yes, because `.extend` means to put **each element** of `tickers` into the list, and the elements of a string are the individual Unicode code points (letters, newline characters etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to separate the items into a list before using `.extend()` by using `.splitlines()`:

```
l = []

tickers = soup.find_all('td', {'aria-label': 'Symbol'})[1:].text

l.extend(tickers.splitlines())
```